# Use of unresolved identifier 'input'

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, barcode-scanner

I'm rewriting my code, but it keep writing this error and i really don't know how to fix it.

It says "Use of unresolved identifier 'input'" at this code:

```
if input != nil {
            session.addInput(input)
        }
        else {
            print(error)
        }
```

The full code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    let session         : AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer    : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var highlightView   : UIView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Allow the view to resize freely
        self.highlightView.autoresizingMask =   [
            .FlexibleTopMargin,
            .FlexibleBottomMargin,
            .FlexibleLeftMargin,
            .FlexibleRightMargin]

        // Select the color you want for the completed scan reticle
        self.highlightView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
        self.highlightView.layer.borderWidth = 3

        // Add it to our controller's view as a subview.
        self.view.addSubview(self.highlightView)


        // For the sake of discussion this is the camera
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        // Create a nilable NSError to hand off to the next method.
        // Make sure to use the "var" keyword and not "let"
        var error : NSError? = nil


        do {
            let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
            _ = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            // Do the rest of your work...
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // Handle any errors
            print(error)
        }

        // If our input is not nil then add it to the session, otherwise we're kind of done!
        if input != nil {
            session.addInput(input)
        }
        else {
            // This is fine for a demo, do something real with this in your app. :)
            print(error)
        }

        let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        session.addOutput(output)
        output.metadataObjectTypes = output.availableMetadataObjectTypes


        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(layer: session) as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        // Start the scanner. You'll have to end it yourself later.
        session.startRunning()

    }

    // This is called when we find a known barcode type with the camera.
    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        var highlightViewRect = CGRectZero

        var barCodeObject : AVMetadataObject!

        var detectionString : String!

        let barCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode
        ]


        // The scanner is capable of capturing multiple 2-dimensional barcodes in one scan.
        for metadata in metadataObjects {

            for barcodeType in barCodeTypes {

                if metadata.type == barcodeType {
                    barCodeObject = self.previewLayer.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject)

                    highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds

                    detectionString = (metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject).stringValue

                    self.session.stopRunning()
                    break
                }

            }
        }

        print(detectionString)
        self.highlightView.frame = highlightViewRect
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.highlightView)

    }


}
```

I'll be very glad if anyone could help me.

Comment: It's as the error says. The compiler has no idea what it is, which means: where did you declare `input`?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is totally right. There is no variable or constant `input` defined in the scope you're using it.

Fix: Define a variable named `input` that matches the types.

**Edit**: what could typematch you are throwing away a few lines up, here:

```
            _ = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
```

[Read up on error handling in swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html). Especially, when cp'ing code from Obj-C:)